# MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE возвращает не читаемую строку

Tags: android, кодировка

Использую

```
String[] projection = {MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION, 
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.YEAR,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID};
Cursor cursor;
cursor = сontext.getContentResolver().query(
             MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,    
             projection, selection, null, null);
```

для получения информации. На реальном устройстве HTC One V все отображается нормально, в эмуляторе же (и на других устройствах) русские буквы отображаются "кракозябрами".

Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить эту проблему?

UPD:
Получаю из `Cusor'а` данные вот так

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Track =" + cursor.getString(3));
    Track track = new Track();
    track.setLocalId(cursor.getInt(0));
    track.setArtist(cursor.getString(1));
    track.setAlbum(cursor.getString(2));
    track.setTitle(cursor.getString(3));
    track.setPath(cursor.getString(4));
    track.setFileName(cursor.getString(5));
    track.setLength(cursor.getLong(6));
    track.setYear(cursor.getInt(7));
    track.setAlbumId(cursor.getLong(8));
    track.setGenre(context.getString(R.string.unknown_genre));
    tracks.add(track);
}
cursor.close();
```

В первом случае получаю в логе Track =Eye of the tiger(OST Рокки Бальбоа),
во втором - Track =Eye of the tiger(OST ?????????? ??????????????)

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего проблема в расшифровке данных, попробуйте разные (UTF-8, ASCII)